# else if statement in javascript not able to display validation message

Tags: javascript, html

I am having trouble displaying strings depending on the if/else statements in my validation.

If you look at the code below, if the `if` statement is met, then it displays the message which is fine, but then when I make sure the `if` statement is met and deliberately fail the `else if` statement, instead of displaying a message, it just displays a blank. Why is it not displaying a message for when `else if` statement is met in javascript validation below:

```
function editvalidation() {
     var isDataValid = true;
     var currentAssesO = document.getElementById("currentAssessment");
     var noStudentsO = document.getElementById("addtextarea");
     var studentAssesMsgO = document.getElementById("studentAlert");

     studentAssesMsgO.innerHTML = "";

     if (currentAssesO.value == ""){
         $('#targetdiv').hide();
         studentAssesMsgO.innerHTML = "Please Select an Assessment to edit from the Assessment Drop Down Menu";
         isDataValid = false; 
     }else if (noStudentsO.value == ""){
         $('#targetdiv').hide();
         studentAssesMsgO.innerHTML = "You have not Selected any Students you wish to Add into Assessment";
         isDataValid = false; 
     }
     else{
         studentAssesMsgO.innerHTML = ""; 
     }

     return isDataValid;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

HTML:

SELECT BOX (Options are appended into this box):

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="addtextarea" id="studentadd" size="10">
</select>
```

DROP DOWN MENU:

```
<select name="session" id="sessionsDrop">
<option value="">Please Select</option>
<option value='20'>EWYGC - 10-01-2013 - 09:00</option>
<option value='22'>WDFRK - 11-01-2013 - 10:05</option>
<option value='23'>XJJVS - 12-01-2013 - 10:00</option>
</select> </p>
```

ALERT MESSAGE:

```
<div id='studentAlert'></div>
```

Reuirements for validation:

- If drop down menu is empty, then display message that assessment needs to be select from drop down menu in alert message div.
- If drop down menu is not empty, then check to see if the select box contains any options, if select box contains no options, then replace div alert message stating no students have been selected to add to assessment
- If drop down menu is not empty and select box is not empty (or in other words contains an option), then div alert message is just an empty string `""`

Comment: @DaveNewton LOL! Seriously? :P

Comment: ^This......................

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Rephrase your JavaScript this way:

```
function editvalidation() {
    var isDataValid = true;
    var currentAssesO = document.getElementById("currentAssessment");
    var noStudentsO = document.getElementById("addtextarea");
    var studentAssesMsgO = document.getElementById("studentAlert");
    var errorMsg = "";

    studentAssesMsgO.innerHTML = "";
    if (currentAssesO.value == "" || noStudentsO.value == "") {
        $('#targetdiv').hide();
        isDataValid = false; 

        if (currentAssesO.value == "") {
            errorMsg += "Please Select an Assessment to edit from the Assessment Drop Down Menu";
        }

        if (noStudentsO.value == "") {
            errorMsg += "You have not Selected any Students you wish to Add into Assessment";
        }

        studentAssesMsgO.innerHTML = errorMsg; // Plus whatever styling for messages.
    }

    return isDataValid;
}
```

---

#### Updated answer

Please include jQuery by putting this in the `<head>` section.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Update your script:

```
function editvalidation()
{
    if ($("#sessionsDrop").val()=="")
        $("#studentAlert").html("Assessment needs to be filled.");
    if ($("#sessionsDrop").val()!="" && $("#studentadd").children().length==0)
        $("#studentAlert").html("No students have been selected to add to assessment.");
    if ($("#sessionsDrop").val()!="" && $("#studentadd").children().length!=0)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried the code above but I am getting a `noStudentsO`  isn null error in console.

Comment: I just like to say btw that #addtextarea is actually a select box not a textarea. I want to check if there are no options

Comment: @user1964964 Fine to use jQuery?

Comment: If you prefer to user jquery then yeah go for it

Comment: @user1964964 Can you update your question with the HTML too? And also, let us know what you wanna do... Update the details in the question. Will update my answer. :)

Comment: @user1964964 Waiting... :)

Comment: Haha, its ok time for me to go sleep as well. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the magic:

```
else {
    studentAssesMsgO.innerHTML = ""; 
    alert(noStudentsO.value); // tell me why I'm in this block
}
```