# Displaying different errors based input types and validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-mvc

Here's something that's been bending my brain recently.

I'm building a Web Application in Spring MVC and some forms include multiple input types (e.g form:radiobuttons [spring radio buttons], select boxes, text fields etc...). 
My goal is to use the .hide() and .show() methods in jQuery to hide/show a div with the ID "msgDiv" underneath the heading ("Select a Color") which is the same on both forms.
What I want to achieve is to use the same validation function for both forms and show/hide custom messaging accordingly.

**Note** *This is just an exercise I made up to ensure proper error handling and validation before altering my Application so overlook the silliness of color choices and music in this example.*

On to the code!

Form1: "Select Form" (select box validation ONLY)
HMTL code snippet:

```
<form:form action="FormA" commandName="user" name="myForm" id="myFormSelect">
    <input type="hidden"  id="color" name="color" value="${requestScope.user.color}" />
        <h2>Select a Color</h2>
        <div id="msgDiv">
            <form:errors path="*"  element="span"  id="errorMsg" /> 
            <span id="message"/></span><br/><br/>
        </div>
        <p>Please select a color</p>

            <select id="userSelect" name"user" class="selectbox_class" style="max-width: 200px;">
                <option value="">--Select One--</option>
                    <%
            Map<String, String> myMap = ( Map<String, String>) session.getAttribute("myMap");
            for (String key:myMap.keySet())
            {
            %>  <option value="<%= key %>"><%out.print(key+"</option>");
            }
            %>
            </select>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <div class="button-panel"><span class="buttons buttons-left"></span>
        <button type="button" class="buttons buttons-middle"  onClick="selectVal();" id="send" value="send">Submit</button>
        <span class="buttons buttons-right"></span>
    </div>
</form:form>
```

Form2: "Select & Radio Form" (select box and radio validation)
HMTL code snippet:

```
<form:form action="FormB" commandName="user" name="mySecondForm" id="mySecondFormSelectAndRadio">
    <input type="hidden"  id="color" name="color" value="${requestScope.user.color}" />
        <h2>Select a Color</h2>
        <div id="msgDiv">
            <form:errors path="*"  element="span"  id="errorMsg" /> 
            <span id="message"/></span><br/><br/>
        </div>
        <p>Please select a color</p>

            <select id="userSelect" name"user" class="selectbox_class" style="max-width: 200px;">
                <option value="">--Select One--</option>
                    <%
            Map<String, String> myMap = ( Map<String, String>) session.getAttribute("myMap");
            for (String key:myMap.keySet())
            {
            %>  <option value="<%= key %>"><%out.print(key+"</option>");
            }
            %>
            </select>
    <br/>
<h2>Music Genre</h2>
<p>Please select the button which describes your taste in music</p>

<form:radiobutton path="music" name="radio" id="radio1" value="classicForm"/><label for="radio1">Classical Music</label><br> 
<form:radiobutton path="music" name="radio"  id="radio2" value="jazzForm"/><label for="radio2">Jazz Music</label><br>
<br>
<div class="button-panel"><span class="buttons buttons-left"></span>
   <button type="button" class="buttons buttons-middle" onClick="history.back(-1)">Back</button>
   <span class="buttons buttons-right"></span>
</div>
<div id="spacer"></div><div id="spacer"></div>
<div class="button-panel">
    <div id="spacer"></div>
    <span class="buttons buttons-left"></span>
    <button type="button" class="buttons buttons-middle"  onClick="selectVal();" id="send" value="send">Submit</button><span class="buttons buttons-right"></span>
</div>
```

*Here's the script section at the bottom of each page so far*

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

<% if (myMap != null) {%>
    $('select[name=userSelect]').change(function() {
        var selVal = $(this).val();
        var txtVal = $("#userSelect option:selected").text();
        $("#color").val(txtVal);    
     }); 

     $('select[name=userSelect]').val($("#color").val());

<%} else { %>
    $("#color").val("${user.color}");
<%} %>
    });

    $(document).ready(function(selectVal) {  
     if ($("#userSelect").val()=="")      
        $("#msgDiv").show();
    return dataValid;
    });
```

And here's my external javascipt file so far:

```
function submitForm(formId)
{
document.getElementById(formId).submit();
}

function selectVal() {
var dataValid = true;
var selector = document.getElementById("userSelect");
var radios = $("input[name=radio]");
var message= document.getElementById("message");
var errorMsg = "";

message.innerHTML = "";
if (selector.value == "" || radios.checked == false) {
    $('#msgDiv').hide();
    dataValid = false; 

    if (selector.value == "") {
        errorMsg += "Please Select an Color from the Drop Down Menu";
    }

    if (radios.checked == false) {
        errorMsg += "Please select a Genre of Music";
    }

    message.innerHTML = errorMsg; 
    }

    return dataValid;
   }
```

Requirements:

1. Div should remain hidden unless validation is not complete even on page load
2. Appropriate error message should appear
3. If user clicks submit without selecting a color or music genre a combined message should appear.

Also here is a similar thread for reference.
[else if statement for validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14269995/else-if-statement-in-javascript-not-able-to-display-validation-message).

Thanks!!

Comment: Don't bother to hide the div.  If there are no errors it will be empty and will not show.

Comment: So far the div shows with or without the errors if i don't use .hide() or display:none...it makes the layout of the page especially in IE look pretty rough

Comment: Consider using jstl logic tags to only show the error div when there are errors.

Comment: That is a good point @DwB but unfortunately in my case I was asked to use javascript/jQuery solely. I will 1+ that as i do find that is a good answer. Any idea what I'm doing wrong in javascript?

Comment: you never call .hide() in your example.  if the functionality is currently "errors show and never go away", this is likely the cause.

Comment: Also, the comment for the line" $(document).ready(function(selectVal" extends and covers the next line.  this means that the line "if ($("#userSelect").val()=="") " is part of the comment and will never execute.

Comment: .hide() is in the js file

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after a few more hours I was able to come up with this answer

- @DWB took out the hide()/show() all together and used .toggle() to switch the display on the page
- Instead of trying to call code from both internal and external scripts I went with the K.I.S.S method. Always a good thing  for beginners or intermediate programmers such as myself to keep in mind. *KEEP IT SIMPLE STUPID*

So instead of **6** functions (2 functions on each html page, 2 methods in a separate file each calling 2 functions) the finished product is:

- **One Function for VALIDATION and One window.onload function call to keep the div hidden onload and reload** in an external file ("yourname.js")

*If you have any questions please message or email me and as always, a different approach is ALWAYS welcome!!*

**SOLUTION:**

```
function customMessageForMultipleInputs()
{
var choicesForm = document.getElementById("choicesForm");

if(radio1.checked=="" && radio2.checked=="" && document.getElementById("userSelect").value=="")
{           selected=false;
        document.getElementById("msgDiv").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("errorMsg").innerHTML="Please select your Favorite Color and
   a Genre of Music";
        return false;

 }
 if(document.getElementById("userSelect").value=="")
 {
        document.getElementById("msgDiv").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("errorMsg").innerHTML="Please select a Color";
        return false;
 }if(document.getElementById("radio1").checked=="" && document.getElementById("radio2").checked=="") 
 {  
selected=false;
document.getElementById("msgDiv").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("errorMsg").innerHTML="Please select a Genre of Music;
     return false;
 }else{   
        document.getElementById("msgDiv").style.display = "none";
        reportOutageConfirm.submit();
        return true;
        document.getElementById("msgDiv").style.display = "none";
 }
 };
window.onload = function() {
customMessageForMultipleInputs();
 };
```

**Here's how it works:**

1. I created a function 'customMessageForMultipleInputs() which is called in my HTML file inside a button on a click event. (e.g. myBTN prop=val, prop=val, onClick="customMessageForMultipleInputs etc..)
2. In my original question I was jumbling up my programming logic. It was easier to just say that the .checked property of my radio buttons (e.g.if(document.getElementById("radio1").checked=="") Similar to the '*value*' of the"userSelect" dropbox.
3. window.onload = function() {
   **customMessageForMultipleInputs**();
    };

Sounds silly but #3 had me for a loop for a bit because I was trying to be "slick" and doing more than what was necessary. For anyone who is new window.onload is essentially ensuring than when a page is displayed (not always rendered however from my experience), this function will fire and the default setting of my error div ('#msgDiv')
will be hidden and remain hidden from the page unless the user has not properly filled out the form.

Anyway, I hope this helps someone one day and THANKS!!!!

I Love this site!! :)